# How to add values dynamically into a python dict and then to a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

My code extracts specific values from API and I need to put these values in an existing JSON file as such

Code :

```
list = ['xxx','yyy','zzz','rrr','ttt']
    for element in list:
ipam_data = get_data(element)
        for k,v in ipam_data.items():
                if 'networks' in v:
                    for network_info in v['networks']:
                        id_site = network_info['site_id']
                        network_subnet = network_info['network']
                        vlan = network_info['vlan']
```

I am trying to put the data in a nested dict with the same keys, multiple values in a JSON file as such :

```
{
            "id_site": "value",
            "vlan_info": "value",
            "network_subnet": "value",
          },
 {
             "id_site": "value",
            "vlan_info": "value",
            "network_subnet": "value",
           },
```

I am having a bit of a challenge with coding my add_data function as I want to add the values to the dict through a loop. I have a classic function that adds a value to a classic dict that I am trying to modify :

```
def add_data(your_dict, new_data):
 your_dict[new_data['mag_id']['ip_range']['vlan']] = new_data
    return your_dict
```

I am trying to add the values dynamically as opposed to writing the values in hard code to the JSON and this is where i am struggling a bit. Any help is welcome.

```
data = {}
new_entry={'mag_id':id_mag,'ip_range':network_info,'vlan':vlan}
add_data(data,new_entry)
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
 json.dump(add_data, fp)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the add_data() function to add data to a dict. You can just add the elements piecewise:

```
data = {}
new_entry={'mag_id':id_mag,'ip_range':network_info,'vlan':vlan}
for key,value in new_entry.items():
    data[key]=value
```

if you absolutely want to make it as a function:

```
def add_data(your_dict, new_data):
    for key,value in new_data.items():
        your_dict[key]=value
    return your_dict
```

Mark that there is no error handling in this function. It will overwrite existing entries with the same key.